# Java Entity Object of Union Query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, dns, entity

I am attempting to create a domain/entity class based on a complex query.  The query unions a bunch of tables together and unfortunately I am not able to create a view on the database for this query.  I have been trying to set up the entity object but I am unsure of how to ensure that the marshaling works properly (and ensure the entity acts as read-only object).
As an example of the query, I am doing something like this:

```
Select 
U_T.a,
U_T.b,
U_T.c,
C_T.a
FROM
(select 
A_T.a,
null as b,
A_T.c,
1 as ind
from A_T
UNION
select
B_T.a,
B_T.b,
null,
0 as ind
FROM B_T
) U_T
left outer join C_T on C_T.fk_a = U_T.a;
```

The other issues are that this union can result in instances where there is no unique key column.  This is fine as this data is for viewing only, and never editing.  However the @Entity annotation wants a column to be listed with the @ID annotation.  Another issue is that I do not believe I can use the other entity classes as the goal is to reduce the number of DB transactions from this query (as the actual one can result in hundreds of recursive queries being performed).

If I need to give any more information please let me know.

Comment: @Thomas I didn't realize there were 2 questions in there and I still only see one question and a list of issue that I am encountering with the problem itself.  Could you please point out which two questions you are seeing so I can update the original post?

Comment: @Thomas I'm not asking how to create a database view for the query, infact I'm stating that I can't create a view for it.  Its not that I don't know how to create the view, it is that I am unable to create the view due to not having the ability to modify the database.